# Erro na Function, System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: vb.net

Eu estou fazendo um sistema de login, Quando se clicka no botão iniciar ele inicia o seguinte código:

```
 Function Prencher2()

    Dim line() As String
    Dim emailsenha As String = List.Lines(0)
    line = Split(emailsenha, "|")
    Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("liubw-user").SetAttribute("value", line(0))
    Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("liubw-password").SetAttribute("value", line(1))
    Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("liubw-submit").InvokeMember("click")
    WaitForPageLoad()
    Verificar()

End Function
```

OBS:List é o nome do textbox

No caso ele vai colocar o email e senha que está na textbox e vai clickar no botão entrar.
Estou usando o método Function porque é muito mais rápido para fazer oque eu quero, porem na parte `emailsenha As String = List.Lines(0)`ele da o erro System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'o índice estava fora dos limites da matriz.'

Oque posso fazer para arrumar isso? Todos meus códigos estão corretos pois já testei manualmente.

Comment: Onde está a declaração e atribuição de valores de List?

Comment: List é o nome do textbox

Comment: Depurando qual é o valor de List?

Comment: este é um codigo que eu peguei que na textbox você insere uma lista de email e senha, nessa textbox vai ficar separado os email e senha assim: email@email.com|senha, o line(0) é o email e o line(1) a senha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peguei o seu código e testei local, e ele funciona normalmente, o problema que no seu teste, você deve estar mandando um valor vazio, por isso esta dando o erro, acho melhor colocar um if para verificar se o que esta vindo do textBox está vazio, coloque antes da linha:

```
Dim emailsenha As String = List.Lines(0)
```